# About template alias

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Given the following code 2 questions arise:

```cpp
template <bool AddOrRemoveRef>
struct Fun_;

template <>
struct Fun_<true> {
    template <typename T> using type = std::add_lvalue_reference<T>;
};

template <>
struct Fun_<false> {
   template <typename T> using type = std::remove_reference<T>;
};

template <typename T>
template<bool AddOrRemove>
using Fun = typename Fun_<AddOrRemove>:: template type<T>;
    
template <typename T> using RomoveRef = Fun<false>;

int main()
{
    RomoveRef<int&>::type j = 1; // ok
    printf("%d\n", j);

    // question 2. I want to use Fun directly, how can i do?
    // template Fun<false>::type<int&> i = 1;
    // printf("%d\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

1.How can I understand the two `template <>` postion?

2.How can I use `Fun::type` or `Fun_::type` to implement the same function as `RomoveRef`?

Answer (score 2):

About the first question, `g++` says that "there are too many parameter lists" where `clang++` says "extraneous template parameter list in alias template declaration".
To make the code compile you should write this:

```
template <bool AddOrRemove, typename T>
using Fun = typename Fun_<AddOrRemove>::template type<T>;
```

About the second function, if I've understand correctly, maybe you want something like

```
template <typename T>
using RomoveRef = Fun<!std::is_reference<T>::value, T>;
```